# Can we make finding duplicates better in the close window?

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close, se-quality-project

The other day I went to close a question as a duplicate of [Resolve header include circular dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-header-include-circular-dependencies).  Normally I just open a new tab, type in *circular inclusion c++* and I get a set of results from google like

[image]

<sup>Used incognito window to try to get unbiased search results</sup>

And you can see the question I'm looking for is right up there at the top.

Instead of doing this though I decided I would search for the question in the close window search box.  I brought that up and typed in *circular inclusion c++* and instead of getting what I was hopping I get

[image]

And lo and behold, the canonical doesn't show up.  I even scrolled all the way through the list and it wasn't present.  Is there anyway we can get this better?  Could we possible have it include the top google or other search engine results if they come from Stack Overflow?

Comment: let me find the dupe for this ...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that dialog uses the same endpoint as for the similar questions list, and it only takes titles into account. The canonical you expect to find doesn't have the word *inclusion* in its title, hence it isn't considered as an option.

Comment: @rene That would explain it.  Just irks me that I can't find stuff easily here but it's so easy to find what I want when I go to google.

Comment: I'm not arguing about Google being a better search engine because it is. For what is offered in the UI it is good to know which dataset is searched and how the search terms are applied and the relevance is determined.

Comment: @rene The SO search is not title based, if you perform the search you see the highlights in the results are almost all in the content. But the post in question does not contain the word "inclusion" in its content either. That's the problem. If you search for "circular include c++" it is the 4th result.

Comment: @LWChris hmm, that seems plausible, yes.